# Unit tests written in .net core not getting discovered in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-devops

I have C# library created in .net standard 2.0 and respective test project built in .netcore31. While opening the solution locally in VS2019, I am able to run all test cases and code coverage is pretty descent, however, in Azure Devops pipeline, even when I select VS2019 agent as build agent, is seems test runner is using below VS2017 for running test cases. How can we update the same to use VS2019?

```
Visual test task in Azure Devops Pipeline is using : ..\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\**\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe
```

Comment: Can you add your build definition to question?

Comment: May I know what's the status of this? Does the **vstest.console.exe** still picking the wrong one?

Comment: I am still getting "Unable to get code coverage data within the maximum wait time."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you configured your pipeline. By UI or YAML?

Based on my known, we does not build in `Visual Studio 2017` into `Windows 2019` agent. See our [public source code](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/scripts/Installers/Windows2019/Install-VS2019.ps1#L179) of [agent](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#visual-studio-2019-enterprise) for more details.

So, I have to say that you need double check your pipeline configuration to see whether the agent selected is `windows-2019`.

Here is what my `Visual Studio Test` task log print:

[image]

If your pipeline configured by UI, please double check the Agent pool selection for Agent job and Pipeline (if it is build pipeline) are all `Windows-2019`.

For YAML pipeline, please ensure it is `vmImage: windows-2019` or `vmImage: windows-latest`